# web applications with opencpu on rstudio server being asked for user and password

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, rstudio-server, opencpu

I've deployed an application using opencpu on Rstudio server. It's running in AWS. However, when I try to access the page, it asks for a user name and password for the first time. If I want to many people to use this, I do not want this to keep popping up on their screen. Rather, it should directly take them to the page. How should I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCPU is not connected to RStudio. If you installed the `opencpu-server` package on your AWS server, anyone should be able to access `http://yourserver.com/ocpu/` on your server.

Comment: my url is <my_ip>:8787(rstudio port). Maybe that's why? I'm running the opencpu app from rstudio server.

Comment: If you install the `opencpu-server` package on Linux, the public server will be available at <your_ip>:80